# VBA docmd.opentable + variable table name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am very new to VBA. I managed to get my head around Powershell and have worked in SQL for years. But this is the most frustrating language!

I have a Form where a user specifies a source from a combo box.

I then have a macro which should lookup a table and a query based on what the use puts in.

So far i have the table name I want in a variable. I want to pass this to docmd.opentable

But have not figured it out :(

```
    Dim str_DeltaTable As String

    str_DeltaTable = DLookup("Table_Delta", "QC_Report_List", "Source = '" & Forms!Main_Form!Source_ComboBox.Text & "'")

    DoCmd.OpenTable "str_DeltaTable" 'Some help here would be ace
```

Thanks from a newb

Rich

Comment: Dont worry i cracked it. Im an idiot

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own questions, AFAIK, so why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `DoCmd.OpenTable str_DeltaTable` without the quotes to pass the variable's value, not its literal  properly.

Also, your use of `.Text` is probably going to cause problems because text boxes in Access only have .Text property while they have the focus (contrary to many other systems). Instead use the `.Value` property, which is always available. It is also the default property, so you can use `Forms!Main_Form!Source_ComboBox.Value` or just `Forms!Main_Form!Source_ComboBox`.